# AnalyticsService: java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to read gservices without permission

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services

I've spent the entire day attempting to fix this, please find the stack trace below, coming from the Google Play Services lib. I changed nothing, i rebuilt the app today and ever since have been given this error. I've tried upgrading GPS to the latest version, rebuilding GPS, downgrading GPS to a previous version, removing various other libraries, explicitly adding the permission it requests and other such niceties... but NOTHING.

if ANYONE can please lend some advice i'd be forever grateful.

```html
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service
com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.AnalyticsService: java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to
read gservices without permission: Neither user 10064 nor current process has
com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES. at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1929) at
android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:117) at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:985) at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:895) at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:653) at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
Method) Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: attempting to read gservices without permission:
Neither user 10064 nor current process has
com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES. at
android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1289) at
android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:1318) at
android.content.ContextWrapper.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextWrapper.java:395) at
imq.c(SourceFile:107) at imq.a(SourceFile:121) at blw.a(SourceFile:276) at blu.b(SourceFile:203) at
blo.c(SourceFile:135) at com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.AnalyticsService.<init
(SourceFile:53) at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method) at
java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409) at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1926) ... 10 more
```